# Java - why Log4j2 is saving logs into .gz file instead of .txt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

Can someone explain me why Log4j2 is saving logs into .gz file? Why not .txt?

I've changed configuration in .xml file to save in .txt and it works, but I'm not sure if it's proper way to use logs?

EDIT

My log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
                pattern="%style{%d{ISO8601}}{black} %highlight{%-5level }[%style{%t}{bright,blue}] %style{%C{1.}}{bright,yellow}: %msg%n%throwable" disableAnsi="false" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                 fileName="./logs/trade-system-logger-log4j2.log"
                 filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/trade-system-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <!-- rollover on startup, daily and when the file reaches
                10 MegaBytes -->
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
                    size="10 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <!-- LOG everything at INFO level -->
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>

    <!-- LOG "com.baeldung*" at TRACE level -->
    <Logger name="com.tradesystem" level="trace"></Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: share the log4j config

Answer (score 1):

because of your filePattern=....log.gz . rolling file will save in .gz file.
try this

```
filePattern="./logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/trade-system-logger-log4j2-%d{-dd-MMMM-yyyy}-%i.log">
```

the rolling file will save with extension '.log'

reference: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using a RollingFile Appender and this will archive the logs in a compressed file.

Please read the documentation: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender